# Get all not hovered elements and do something with them

Tags: jquery, css, hover

My problem is probably quite simple, but somehow I can’t get it fixed. In a group of objects with one object hovered over, I’d like the hovered object to remain unchanged, but all others are supposed to change.

To be more specific: I have an unordered list of menu-items. Whenever I hover over one of them, all the other items are supposed to become smaller. When I "unhover" the item they should change back again.

I found this post, but it’s answers didn’t work for me:
[Set style for not not hovered elements only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9685073/set-style-for-not-not-hovered-elements-only)

This is what I tried so far:

```
/*This is the default size*/
#navigation ul li a
{
    font-size: 14px;    
}
/*When the list is hovered, change font-size (does’nt work)*/
#navigation ul:hover
{
    font-size: 13px;    
}
/*When the a menu-item is hovered change it’s font-size back to default*/
#navigation ul li a:hover
{
    font-size: 14px;    
}
```

This is one of the answers I found in the post I mentioned. It would be great if it could be done that simply with plain CSS. But it’s not working. Did I do something wrong?

I also tried something with jQuery, although I’m not an expert.

```
for(var i=1; i <= anzahlNavipunkte; i++)
{
    var naviId = "navi" + i; // id name for every menu-item
    var currentMenuItem = "#navigation li:nth-child(" + i + ") a"; 

    $(currentMenuItem).attr('id', naviId); // gives the current menu-item a specific id

    $('#navigation li a').hover(function()
    {   
        var hoveredId = $(this).attr("id"); // get the id of of the hovered element

        $('#' + hoveredId).hover(function()
        {   
            console.log(hoveredId);
            $('#' + hoveredId).css('font-size', '14px'); // hovered element gets default font-size
            $('#navigation ul').css('font-size', '13px'); // other elements change to 13px
        }, function()
        {
            $('#navigation ul').css('font-size', '14px'); // other elements change back
        })
    });
};
```

It doesn’t work, either. Probably because it’s the same approach as with the plain CSS-solution. Can anybody help me out?

I hope my explanation is understandable. If there are questions left please ask.

Comment: Can you post your `html` here or make a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML:

```
<div id="container" >
   <div id="children">
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container:HOVER #children {
    /* your style */
}
```

Try this...

Comment: Agreed, **+1**, and may I offer a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/UFwAJ/) I was proof-of-concepting with =)

Answer (score 0):

Because of specificity `#navigation ul li` overrides  `#navigation ul:hover` that's why your ruleset does not work.
Add  'a'  in your list:hover rule and you should be fine

```
#navigation ul:hover a
{
   font-size: 13px;    
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DRJCg/

Answer (score 0):

insted of `#navigation ul`, i think it sould be `#navigation ul li`

a more direct way would be to add a class to your li and point to the class instead.

i youd use a function li so:

```
function reduceOtherLi(li_to_keep_big){
 var eList = $('#navigation ul li')`//put all the li in an array
    // for each li in the array
    for (i=0; i<eList.length; i++){
        var e = eList[i]; //get current li

        //if it not the clicked one, make the size smalle
        if (e != li_to_keep_big) $(e).css({'font-size':'13px'}); 
        else $(e).css({'font-size':'14px'});
    }
}
```

then you can use the mouseover handler to trigger the function

```
$("#navigation ul li").mouseover(function() { reduceOtherLi(this);});
```

to reset them simply add the folowing line:

```
$("#navigation ul li").mouseout(function() { $('#navigation ul li').css({'font-size':'14px'});});
```

Basicly you can just putt al this in a  tag an it sould work like you want.

Notice the .css(), you could easily use .addClass() and .removeClass() instead and specify the font-size (and bunh of other css) in there.

As for the event handler, the 'this' will repesent the hoverred element. and be passe as the li_to_keep_big.

hope this helps.

Comment: i would definitively creat a css clas for your 'hoverable' list item. would be way easyeir to simply use the $('.className') pointer

Comment: "put all the li in array" - I'd rather use each function.